# how can I add a dependant custom field through the manifest.php

Tags: sugarcrm

I am currently adding a web hook and want to add some fields programmatically through the manifest.php.

I have found the relevent information to add fields as below:

```
'custom_fields' => array (
array (
    'name' => 'text_c',
    'label' => 'LBL_TEXT_C',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'max_size' => 255,
    'require_option' => 'optional',
    'default_value' => '',
    'ext1' => '',
    'ext2' => '',
    'ext3' => '',
    'audited' => 1,
    'module' => 'Accounts'
    )
);
```

the issue is that I cant seem to find how to make the fields dependant i.e. they will only be visible if another field contains a specific value.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the definition array you would need to add the dependency attribute like so :

```
'custom_fields' => array (
array (
    'name' => 'text_c',
    'label' => 'LBL_TEXT_C',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'max_size' => 255,
    'require_option' => 'optional',
    'default_value' => '',
    'ext1' => '',
    'ext2' => '',
    'ext3' => '',
    'audited' => 1,
    'module' => 'Accounts'
    'dependency' => 'equal($other_field,"other field value")'
    )
);
```

This would replicate setting the dependency option in Studio.

The dependency formula

```
'equal($other_field,"other field value")'
```

Means show this field when the another field **other_field** equals the string **"other field value"**

Comment: Hi paquino thank you for the answer.
if the solution is as simple as this, I'm just wondering if it is possible to add custom properties and reference them in a logic hook.